# How to display Picture in picture for video files in .webm format, using NodeJS

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, webm

Can someone please guide me How I could display one video file inside of another (Picture in picture), I have both the videos in .webm format.

Any pointers/ guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would an example using the ffmpeg command-line tool suffice?

Comment: May not suffice, but it would be great to have something that I could start with.

Answer (score 3):

Example using `ffmpeg` command-line tool using [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay), and [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filters:

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i main.webm -i pip.webm -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw/3:-1[pip];[0][pip]overlay=W-w-10:10:shortest=1[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Example assumes both inputs are the same size and you want to mix audio from both inputs.